# How to wipe chrome os from my dual booted chromebook

Tags: dual-boot, fdisk, chrome-book

Ok, so I have a Acer c720 that runs GalliumOS, of which I can use blender on, and Chrome OS, which I really don't use that much, as I have chromium on GalliumOS. I want to work on more projects with blender, so I'd like to wipe the space from Chrome OS to use on Gallium OS. The problem is, I don't know where my partitions are. I downloaded this using chrx, if that is any help. Thank you!

Comment: Please show up the output of fdisk -l

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can (**Only if your Chomebook runs Intel**), but it's extremly technical to do :

[Thread from a GalliumOS team member that explains in gross what to do](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalliumOS/comments/e7ydmk/how_to_remove_chromeos_completely/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

[And a more in depth explanation of what to do to actually delete ChromeOS](http://blog.zxwind.info/2016/03/19/Replace-Chrome-OS-with-Linux-on-Acer-Chromebook-15/)